# JavaScript not able to replace String with Number of same words

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a particular word in String. This word has repeated many times. this is my String:**($scope.selectedText)**

```
 <span style="font-size:20px>This is some text</span>
<span style="font-size:30px>This is some text</span>
<span style="font-size:25px>This is some text</span>
```

I am trying to replace font-size like this:

```
  var font = "font-size:"+15+".000";
  var formatting = $scope.selectedText.replace("font-size:",font);
```

But this ends in just changing the first fonr-size i.e

```
 <span style="font-size:15px>This is some text</span>
    <span style="font-size:30px>This is some text</span>
    <span style="font-size:25px>This is some text</span>
```

Can i know where i am doing it wrong?? I know we can do this programitically , But this is an execption! ThankYou.

Comment: You don't want to use CSS?

Comment: No i cant in my case

Comment: we need to see how you declare $scope.selectedText. Imho, you declare it to just contain the first span element of the dom, => you need to get all spans via getElementByClass or s.th. similar, and then do a foreach-loop.

Comment: i get all the spans. Can you show me how we can replace all spans using for each

Comment: i get all the spans. Can you show me how we can replace all spans using for each

Comment: The javascipt function `replace()` only replaces one occurrence if both operands are text (string).

To replace all occurrences you need to use a Regular Expression with the "g" modifier (g = global). But then you still don't get what you presumably want because it replaces only the `font-size:` parts and not the `##px` parts that follow them each time. See the answer by Ingvi for a better approach to all this.

Comment: to replace all occurrences including the ##px part , you can use a regex expression

string = string.replace(/font-size:.+"/g, 'font-size:15px"');

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontSize = 15 + "px";
}
```

there is a missing closing quote mark in your markup:

```
<span style="font-size:20px">This is some text</span>
<span style="font-size:30px">This is some text</span>
<span style="font-size:25px">This is some text</span>
```

http://codepen.io/ingvi/pen/EKoyrj